# how to pass query params to azure function when calling from action group

Tags: azure, azure-functions, alert, azure-monitoring

I am trying to figure out a usecase.
We want to monitor our machine learning computes and shut them down if they cross the budget threshold.
For this, I am planning to do below things but yet not able to achieve it.

create azure function which accepts a subscription and resource group as query params. It can then use MASL SDK to get the access token. And then find out the workspaces under an resource groups and then query all the computes under that workspace and shut them down.

create action group which will call this function. (Not able to figure out how to pass this subscription and resource id to function app).

create budget to monitor the resource group and use the action group created at step 2.

Please guide me how to update the function URL so that it accepts query param to invoke the function job.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/cost-management-budget-scenario#create-an-azure-logic-app-for-orchestration), looks like your function app already gets the information it needs in the body of the request like this

```json
{
  "schemaId":"AIP Budget Notification",
  "data": {
    "SubscriptionName":"CCM - Microsoft Azure Enterprise - 1",
    "SubscriptionId":"<GUID>",
    "SpendingAmount":"100",
    "BudgetStartDate":"6/1/2018",
    "Budget":"50",
    "Unit":"USD",
    "BudgetCreator":"email@contoso.com",
    "BudgetName":"BudgetName",
    "BudgetType":"Cost",
    "ResourceGroup":"",
    "NotificationThresholdAmount":"0.8"
  }
}
```